# Merge redundant information in signe dataframe by index

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to merge differents information in a single dataframe depending on the index of the cell.
Explanation :
I want to have initially array looking like this :
[Initial Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOwdO.png)
... to be like this in the end :
[Final Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0tkH.png).
For the identical index, I want to merge the information of both parameter in a single line.

I want to do this using dataframe array, can someone please help ?
I have an initial code looking like this at the moment, but with an initial array looking like the 1st one with parameters for same code in differents line :

```
dataraw=pd.read_csv('Donne.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
data=dataRaw.groupby('Code')
```

Thanks in advance,
Sorry for images instead of array, do not have time to work on layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate by `sum` and `fillna` :

```
dataraw.groupby(['Code']).sum().fillna(0).reset_index()

   Code P1  P2
0   a   1.0 8.0
1   b   3.0 4.0
2   c   4.0 0.0
3   d   0.0 7.0
```